# Identifying Centralized Repo for CVS

Tags: cvs

I was given a directory of files that were under CVS control.  However, how can I identify which of the dirs is the centralized repo for CVS (and not a checked out version on a local directory).

Answer (score 2):

The centralised CVS repository will have a directory `CVSROOT` containing repository configuration and other subdirectories in the repository structure. All of the checked-in files will have a `,v` suffix (RCS-style) on their extension. Deleted files will be in subdirectories `attic`.

Checked out versions have a `CVS` subdirectory in every folder. There'll be files in containing the checkout source (`root` or `repository` - I forget) and current tag / branch if appropriate (`tag` - first letter N for tag or B for branch I think).

Answer (score 1):

[See this](http://durak.org/cvswebsites/doc/cvs_12.php#SEC12).

The CVS repository will contain the RCS files (generally ending in `,v`).

I'd seriously consider migrating the repository to something other than CVS (Git, Hg, even SVN).

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the CVS directories from a checked out area, you can look in CVS/Root to get the location of the CVS repository and in CVS/Repository files path for that directory relative to the root.